# A poem and a number sequence

Tags: riddle, pattern, rhyme, number-sequence

You wake up on the floor of an empty room without having any recollection of how you got there. The room is very dimly lit and it takes a while before your eyes are adapted to the darkness. There is only one way out of the room: a big metal door that appears to be closed. As you approach it you notice there's a number pad and what looks like a LED display on the wall next to the door. Getting closer you can see that there's a poem and some number sequence engraved into the wall as well:

[image]

The number sequence goes:

> $12,021,831,443,517,636,671,582,92,91,??$

And the poem reads:

> ACCESS IS FORBIDDEN
>   SAVE YOURSELF NOW
>   BY THESE NUMBERS HIDDEN
>   AND SPUN SOMEHOW
>
> BEGIN WITH THE FIRST
>   AND TURN IT ROUND
>   THE WORDS YET REVERSED
>   READ WHAT YOU'VE FOUND
>
> REMOVE THE LETTERS
>   ALL BUT ONE
>   OBSERVE WHAT MATTERS
>   THEN YOU'RE DONE
>
> MOVE ON TO THE NEXT
>   THE PROCEDURE'S THE SAME
>   READ OUT THE TEXT
>   AND TELL ME ITS NAME
>
> ONCE YOU HAVE SPOTTED
>   WHAT THIS IS ABOUT
>   MAKE SURE YOU'VE GOT IT
>   AND LET YOURSELF OUT

You quickly figure out that the next number in the sequence is most likely going to be the code to unlock the door, while the cryptic poem seems to provide some clues on how to crack the pattern...

Can you escape?

Comment: @Levieux-Can you pass a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next number to the sequence will be ->

> **1151**

If we do as said -

> We have a sequence - 12,021,831,443,517,636,671,582,92,91,??

BEGIN WITH THE FIRST
AND TURN IT ROUND
THE WORDS YET REVERSED
READ WHAT YOU'VE FOUND

> Let's take the first which is -> **12**
> Turning it around gives -> 21 -> **TWENTY ONE**
> Reversing the words gives -> **ENOYTNEWT**

REMOVE THE LETTERS
ALL BUT ONE
OBSERVE WHAT MATTERS
THEN YOU'RE DONE

> After removing all the letters from **ENOYTNEWT** except ONE, we get **ONE**

Lets try to do the same with other's by

021 -

> 021 -> Reversed -> **120**
>  120 -> **ONE TWENTY** -> Reversed -> **YTNEWTENO**
>  Removing all letters except **TWO** we get **TWO***(incremented by one)

831 -

> 831 -> Reversed -> **138**
>  138 -> **ONE HUNDRED THIRTY EIGHT** -> Reversed -> **THGIEYTRIHTDERDNUHENO**
>  Removing all letters except **THREE** we get **THREE***

443 -

> 443 -> Reversed -> **344**
>  344 -> **THREE HUNDRED FORTY FOUR** -> Reversed -> **RUOFYTROFDERDNUHEERHT**
>  Removing all letters except **FOUR** we get **FOUR***

517 -

> 517 -> Reversed -> **715**
>  715-> **SEVEN HUNDRED FIFTEEN** -> Reversed -> **NEETFIFDERDNUHNEVES**
>  Removing all letters except **FIVE** we get **FIVE***

636 -

> 636 -> Reversed -> **636**
>  636-> **SIX HUNDRED THIRTY SIX** -> Reversed -> **XISYTRIHTDERDNUHXIS**
>  Removing all letters except **SIX** we get **SIX***

671-

> 671-> Reversed -> **176**
>  176-> **ONE HUNDRED SEVENTY SIX** -> Reversed -> **XISYTNEVESDERDNUHENO**
>  Removing all letters except **SEVEN** we get **SEVEN***

582-

> 582-> Reversed -> **285**
>  285-> **TWO HUNDRED EIGHTY FIVE** -> Reversed -> **EVIFYTHGIEDERDNUHOWT**
>  Removing all letters except **EIGHT** we get **EIGHT***

92-

> 92-> Reversed -> **29**
>  29-> **TWENTY NINE** -> Reversed -> **ENINYTNEWT**
>  Removing all letters except **NINE** we get **NINE***

So, lets get to the last number

91

> 91-> Reversed -> **19**
>  19-> **NINETEEN** -> Reversed -> **NEETENIN**
>  Removing all letters except **TEN** we get **TEN**

So,

> The next number should produce ELEVEN in the reversed string. Hence, the answer can be **1511**

How -

> 1151 -> 1511 -> ONE THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED ELEVEN ->  **NEVELEDERDNUHEVIFDNASUOHTENO**
>  Removing all except ELEVEN gives - > **ELEVEN**

So, the code is

> 1151. Reason being, when the words are reversed it gives respective number in words. And the original number is the lowest of all to follow the pattern. Thanks to @M Oehm for figuring this out.

Comment: Cool! I think you have it, but the code should be 1511 in my opinion, because each of the other numbers in the series are the smallest number than can be reversed and contain letters of ONE to TEN in order.

Comment: @MOehm- That was it. Thanks. Let me edit. :)

Comment: I've been offline for quite a while, but this is indeed the correct answer. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this one is right - I tried to follow the riddle and I got this:

> seven - 99
>
>  eight - 9
>
>  four - 0
>
>  five - 9
>
>  six - 0(No number)
>
>  one - 90
>
>  two - 0
>
>  three - 99
>
>  zero - 09

What I did:

> I converted it to words and turned it around. What happened is that almost all words, when turned around, have a number 9. Then I added it all up my answer was 315.
>
>  *(wild guess)*

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better your line of thinking?

Comment: well reading the word in turn around gives you a number for example seven you see that when you turn it around the letter e turns to 9 then repeat it just remove the letters that will not turn into numbers when flipped

Comment: so if im not mistaken, if we will type the code then this is the final output 12,021,831,443,517,636,671,582,92,91,?? where ?? = 135

Comment: no not that kind he said read the word reversed

Comment: sorry i mean turn around try to imagine the word `seven` turn it around starting from `n` so what will you see that e turns to 9

Comment: wow i didnt notice that, your right but on seven since there are 2 (9)'s i just combined but then let me edit my answer.

Comment: Done editing sir, How about you sir whats your line of thinking in this code? Actually i have a douht especially on the computation part because the poem doesnt point to sum it except it is noticeable full of 9's

Comment: @CrimsonGuard: you're not on the right track. Look at what Techidiot did (and what I commented) and go from there.

Comment: OMG i think I just need to improve my logic and critical thnking, I didnt notice that that the number to be used is number seq. I used the keypad hahah WTF. :/